# How to store data in DB related to problem

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I would like to ask because this makes me bald since last week.

I have to make a complaint form for stores for our products.
We have some contractors and they have their own stores/resellers.
Each reseller has own link to the same form with just a list of stores related to only one contractor.

Already I have multiple tables (as many as I have contractors) with stores inside each.

I wanted to upgrade script with some features and decided to rebuild database.

But have a question - better is to have one table with all stores from all contractors or to have multiple tables for each contractor separately? What is the safest option.

I know that if database will be compromised - all tables will be visible, so all in all there is no difference.

Just thinking - based on your better than mine experience:
 - better is to switch "tablename" in MySQL connection related to URL (like I already have)
 or
- better is to have one "tablename" with i.e. "contractor" column to select only stores related to contractor?

I will be thankful for your opinion and explanations (if you can) - what and why is the best.

Comment: Without wishing to cause further hair loss, this question seems a little broad for this forum

Comment: I would recommend you to evaluate pros and cons of having one table name with contractor column. If your database is compromised, all the tables in the db will be compromised, so how does creating multiple help in this case ?